# Importing .pfx within BouncyCastle-Keystore

Tags: certificate, bouncycastle, x509

i've a problem concerning the import of a .pfx certificate into a bouncycastle-keystore. The error message says that "...tampered keystore file or incorrect PKCS12 Password...". I've exported the certificates with Windows' CertMgr.

The certificates are exported as .pfx files. I want to import the certificates with their private keys in order to use them in combination with tls' client authentication.

I would appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your case - but a lot of tools have implied assumptions about having a password on the private key and/or the same on the PKCS#12 enclosure; it being the same and being 4 or 6 chars. I found that using something like 'abcd1234' is a fairly safe one to use across vendors (or a real one of course).

Comment: The Problem was, that the key was to long

Answer (score 5):

Windows's PFX files are just renamed PKCS#12 files, and you don't even need BouncyCastle to import them: you can use Java's built-in KeyStore API (which has no limitations on password length or composition -- if you want "no password" you can use the empty string).

Usually, PKCS12 / PFX import code looks something like this:

```
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("your.pfx");
 String password = "your-password";

 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
 ks.load(fis, password.toCharArray());
 String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();

 PrivateKey pKey = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
 X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)ks.getCertificate(alias);
```